# Varnish Docker image not working for node js On localhost

Tags: docker, dockerfile, varnish, varnish-vcl

I am trying to implement Varnish  for a small small node js server

```
(index.js)
const port = 80;
require("http").createServer((req, res) => {
    res.write(new Date().toISOString());
    res.end();
}).listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`http://127.0.0.1:${port}/`);
})
```

```
(default.vcl)
vcl 4.1;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "80";
}
```

```
(CMD)
//now I run docker  with following commands
docker run  --name varnish -p 8080:80   -e VARNISH_SIZE=2G  varnish:stable
docker cp default.vcl varnish:/etc/varnish 
(Followed By restart container)
```

But All i see is following error:

Error 503 Backend fetch failed
Backend fetch failed

Guru Meditation:
XID: 31

Varnish cache server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem in your varnish configuration. You have set:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "80";
}
```

But `127.0.0.1` (or `localhost`) means "this container", and your backend is not running inside the same container as Varnish. If your node.js server is running on your *host*, you probably want to do something like this:

```
vcl 4.1;

backend default {
    .host = "host.docker.internal";
    .port = "80";
}
```

And then start the container like this:

```
docker run  --name varnish -p 8080:80 --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway  -e VARNISH_SIZE=2G  varnish:stable
```

This maps the hostname `host.docker.internal` to mean "the host on which Docker is running".

---

If your node.js is running in another container, the solution is going to look a little different.